# PHP contact form works under ie mywebsite.com/php/form.php but not when its set as default index.php ie mywebsite.com

Tags: php

Newbie here, I found the problem when I tried to implement the code onto my website, which is made with bootstrap. I also made this weather scraper with bootstrap and php and that one ended up working under the default index.php ie. website.com

Code. Replaced my email with myEmail

PHP

```
<?php

if ($_POST["submit"]) {



    if (!$_POST['name']) {

        $error="<br />Please enter your name";

    }

    if (!$_POST['email']) {

        $error.="<br />Please enter your email address";

    }

    if (!$_POST['comment']) {

        $error.="<br />Please enter a comment";

    }

    if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],     FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    } 


    if ($error) {

    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were errors(s) in          your form:</strong>'.$error.' </div>';

    } else {

    if (mail("myEmail", "Comment from Website!", "Name: ".$_POST['name']."

    Email: ".$_POST['email']."

    Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) {

        $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong>I\'ll be in touch.</div>';

    } else {

                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Sorry, there was an error 
                sending your message. Please try again.</strong></div>';

    }   




    }   


}
```

?>

HTML

```
<body>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 emailForm">

            <h1>Email Us</h1>

            <?php echo $result; ?>

            <p class="lead">Please get in touch, and we will get back to you asap.</p>


        <form method="post">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"
                value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" value="<?php echo $_POST['comment']; ?>"></textarea>

            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />


        </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you share the code that works? paste it in your question. include the form with html with the one what works and we'll try to see why it doesn't work on default index.php

Comment: Ooops, just sent the old crystal ball out for its monthly maintenance. Can you share some code and markup where this behavior is/is not occurring?

Comment: How about a great big ***huh?!*** - What do you think Sam? - @JayBlanchard I found my pick btw. T'was in my wee side pocket.

Comment: @jay: if tea leaves fail, we'll have to read the entrails of a goat sacrified under the light of a 3/4 full moon.

Comment: ah, the crescent moon. Falling under its charm again.

Comment: I have the shiv ready  @JayBlanchard can I borrow a mask?

Comment: @JayBlanchard For the potential spatter.

Comment: just add the full url to the from action .... with form.php, sry

Comment: How could you possibly know that would work @superduperawesomephpexpert?

Comment: @JayBlanchard *How could you possibly know that would work* I think the name explains it -> `superduperawesomephpexpert` (Now I also joined the tea party here :)

Comment: Just a way to be ironic here? or something to start one thinking

Comment: No guessing @superduperawesomephpexpert. If you can't see it you cannot guess what the fix might be. We're all waiting for the OP to return with code but his dump truck might not be running.

Comment: guess what the fix might be - but i can open doors wehn i kick in ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hilarious movie; I lost count how many times I saw it. *A classic*.

Comment: Ok, lets give the question an down vote an go on ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Me too! I go an integer overflow and the count got messed up, just waiting for PHP 7 to get 64bit integers for windows and I can start the count again a bit higher

Comment: Are PHP and HTML placed together in the same file?

Comment: Yeah they are in the same file

Comment: @someone anybody, i took too long sorry

Comment: @s.d.a.p.e help, tried url in form action.

Comment: @unixmiah could you help out please, ill be around this time

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any obvious but try this:

```
<form method="post">
```

to

```
 <form method="post" action="/index.php">
```

If the location of the PHP code is http://website.com/index.php